# BigQuery - Convert Array of dates into string

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have a table in `Big Query`, with some fields that are arrays of dates (type Date Repeated). I need to convert them into a string. For arrays of strings fields I am doing it as below, and it works fine:

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(national_id, "|", "") AS national_id
```

But when the field is an array of dates I´m getting below error.

> *No matching signature for function ARRAY_TO_STRING for argument types: ARRAY, STRING, STRING. Supported signatures:
>   ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY, STRING, [STRING]);
>   ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY, BYTES, [BYTES]) at [41:1]*

I also tried casting date to string as below:

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(cast(natural_person_date_of_birth_list as string), "|", "") AS natural_person_date_of_birth_list,
```

But I´m getting below error:

> *Invalid cast from ARRAY to STRING at [41:22].*

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

You can use a subquery in the select list to transform the dates into strings. For example,

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(national_id, "|", "") AS national_id,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(date, "|") FROM UNNEST(natural_person_date_of_birth_list)) AS dates_of_birth
FROM YourTable;
```

The advantage of this approach is that you get a string for every row, which it sounds like you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `unnest()`:

```
select string_agg(cast(dte as string), '|')
FROM (select [date('2017-01-01'), date('2018-01-01')] as aofd
     ) d,
     unnest(aofd) as dte
```

Answer (score 1):

See two options below. Both for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(natural_person_date_of_birth_list), r'\[|\]|"', ''), ',', '|') dates_string_1,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', d), "|") 
    FROM UNNEST(natural_person_date_of_birth_list) d) AS dates_string_2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

below is just for you quick test and play with it:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT [CURRENT_DATE(), DATE '2011-10-15'] natural_person_date_of_birth_list
)
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(natural_person_date_of_birth_list), r'\[|\]|"', ''), ',', '|') dates_string_1,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', d), "|") 
    FROM UNNEST(natural_person_date_of_birth_list) d) AS dates_string_2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

both options return what I believe is expected:

```sql
dates_string_1           dates_string_2  
2017-11-01|2011-10-15    2017-11-01|2011-10-15
```

Note: the benefit of second option is that you can control order of dates in your list, for example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT [CURRENT_DATE(), DATE '2011-10-15'] natural_person_date_of_birth_list
)
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(natural_person_date_of_birth_list), r'\[|\]|"', ''), ',', '|') dates_string_1,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', d), "|" ORDER BY d) 
    FROM UNNEST(natural_person_date_of_birth_list) d
  ) AS dates_string_2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Here output will be as (note change in dates_string_2)

```sql
dates_string_1          dates_string_2   
2017-11-01|2011-10-15   2011-10-15|2017-11-01
```